# How to use a DateTime in a where clause in Sqlite.Net

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-sql, sqlite.net, zumero

I am writing a mobile application which uses `Sqlite.Net` I am trying to filter my `Table` using a `DateTime` property and **LINQ to SQL**

I have the following piece of code:

```
 var validDates = Database.Connection.Table<Dates>()
        .Where(x => x.StartDate <= DateTime.Today && x.EndDate >= DateTime.Today)
       .ToList();
```

But this Throws an **Object Reference Not Set to the instance of an object** And the stacktrace seems to suggest the error is in the `Sqlite.Net` library which leads me to beleive I am not using `DateTimes` correctly.

> Warning: Unhandled exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 09-28
>   13:01:24.293 W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at
>   SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs) [0x00613] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  09-28 13:01:24.293
>   W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs) [0x0064b] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  09-28 13:01:24.293
>   W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs) [0x00027] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  09-28 13:01:24.293
>   W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr
>   (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs) [0x00027] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  09-28 13:01:24.293
>   W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at
>   SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].GenerateCommand (System.String
>   selectionList) [0x0006d] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 
>   09-28 13:01:24.293 W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at
>   SQLite.Net.TableQuery`1[T].GetEnumerator () [0x00008] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  09-28 13:01:24.293
>   W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) [0x00073] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs:98
>   09-28 13:01:24.293 W/Xamarin.Insights(31238):   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource]
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00011] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:861

Doing it as a sql statemnet like this works:

```
 var query = string.Format("Select * from [Dates.Dates] where StartDate<=date('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}') and EndDate>=date('{1:yyyy-MM-dd}')", DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today);
```

But is there a way to do a `DateTime` query using **LINQ to SQL**?

[Here is the source and method it is erroring in](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L2779)

**Extra Info**

My `StoreDateTimeAsTicks` setting is set to `True`

And My definitions for `StartDate` and `EndDate` are both `DateTimes`

My `Dates` class looks like this:

```
[Table("Dates.Dates")]
public class Dates : BaseModel
{
    public Dates()
    {
        //Don't fire notifications by default, since
        //they make editing the properties difficult.
        this.NotifyIfPropertiesChange = false;
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    [NotNull]
    [AutoIncrement, Column("Id")]
    public int Id 
    { 
        get { return Id_private; }
        set { SetProperty(Id_private, value, (val) => { Id_private = val; }, Id_PropertyName); }
    }
    public static string Id_PropertyName = "Id";
    private int Id_private;

    [NotNull]
    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return Name_private; }
        set { SetProperty(Name_private, value, (val) => { Name_private = val; }, Name_PropertyName); }
    }
    public static string Name_PropertyName = "Name";
    private string Name_private;

    [NotNull]
    [Column("StartDate")]

    // The actual column definition, as seen in SQLite
    public string StartDate_raw { get; set; }

    public static string StartDate_PropertyName = "StartDate";

    // A helper definition that will not be saved to SQLite directly.
    // This property reads and writes to the _raw property.
    [Ignore]
    public DateTime StartDate { 
        // Watch out for time zones, as they are not encoded into
        // the database. Here, I make no assumptions about time
        // zones.
        get { return StartDate_raw != null ? DateTime.Parse(StartDate_raw) : StartDate = DateTime.Now; }
        set { SetProperty(StartDate_raw, StartDate_ConvertToString(value), (val) => { StartDate_raw = val; }, StartDate_PropertyName); }
    }

    // This static method is helpful when you need to query
    // on the raw value.
    public static string StartDate_ConvertToString(DateTime date)
    {    
        return date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");     
    }           

    [NotNull]
    [Column("EndDate")]

    // The actual column definition, as seen in SQLite
    public string EndDate_raw { get; set; }

    public static string EndDate_PropertyName = "EndDate";

    // A helper definition that will not be saved to SQLite directly.
    // This property reads and writes to the _raw property.
    [Ignore]
    public DateTime EndDate { 
        // Watch out for time zones, as they are not encoded into
        // the database. Here, I make no assumptions about time
        // zones.
        get { return EndDate_raw != null ? DateTime.Parse(EndDate_raw) : EndDate = DateTime.Now; }
        set { SetProperty(EndDate_raw, EndDate_ConvertToString(value), (val) => { EndDate_raw = val; }, EndDate_PropertyName); }
    }

    // This static method is helpful when you need to query
    // on the raw value.
    public static string EndDate_ConvertToString(DateTime date)
    {    
        return date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");     
    }
}
```

Comment: @mybirthname No, its not duplicate. It has entirely different context.

Comment: Have you tried to set DateTime.Today into a variable? There are some LINQ providers that doesn't support functions (or behavior like a function) into the LINQ statements.

Comment: @A.DIMO Just tried it and its still erroring sadly

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've updated the question with the relevant info

Comment: That does make a lot of difference. Your actual Db columns are String, not DateTime.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `Sqlite.Net` represents a `DateTime` as a `string` there is no such thing as a `DateTime` in `Sqlite.Net` see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: No but sqlite.net can store it as ticks. And the query engine knows how to deal with that (in combination with DateTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that my `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties in my class **AREN'T** the columns. They are just wrappers for the real `StartDate_Raw` and `EndDate_Raw` properties. Which are `strings`.

Because the `Raw` columns were strings this meant I also can't filter the database using **LINQ to SQL** using string dates, so I was pretty stumped.

The limitation that my dates were stored as strings is a limitation of some third party software I am using called *Zumero*. If I hadn't been using this I would have just changed my table schema to be int instead.

So what I ended up doing was chaning all my `DateTime` columns in my SQL database to be **Ticks** and stored as `Ints` this meant I could change my `string` DateTime property to `int` and use the LINQ to SQL like so:

```
var validDates = Database.Connection.Table<Dates>()
        .Where(x => x.StartDate_Raw <= DateTime.Today && x.EndDate_Raw >= DateTime.Today)
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string dateToday = DateTime.Today;
var validDates = Database.Connection.Table<Dates>().Where(x => x.StartDate <= dateToday && x.EndDate >= dateToday).ToList();
```

Comment: have you tried this out? It is still erroring at my end

Comment: No I didn't. Does your simple query work `Database.Connection.Table<Dates>()` without this datetime condition?

Comment: yes it returns the whole table. I can't help but feel it may be linked with the fact that Sqlite stores `DateTimes` as strings and not actual `DateTimes`

Comment: What is the sql query this linq query generates?

Comment: Select * from [Dates]. but the one in this answer doesnt generate sql it still just crashes before it reaches that